# Laravel 5.7 sharing cookie across domain.com and www.domain.com

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

How do I share cookies between a domain.com and www.domain.com on the same domain in Laravel?  I am not trying to touch my apache files because I have https running on the site and don't want to break anything.   However, going through Laravel documentation I found config/sessions.php file with the following default.

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null);

I tried setting it to 'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'domain.com', 'www.domain.com');

But that didn't help. Basically if a user logs in using domain.com I want the cookie to be valid for www.domain.com too. I have a cookie name setup in the sessions.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using .htaccess file public folder

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please add http:// before the www.domain.com